How CREATE and buffers works?
This code create a buffer:
: bytes create allot does> + ; 

When you execute
10 bytes a

create first create the header for the definition, and then insert one operation that pushed next address into the stack.
Then allot allocates 10 bytes, and then the rest of the instructions (whatever they are).

My question is How the execution jump around the 10 bytes buffer?


How the execution jump around the 10 bytes buffer?

It does not jump, and there are no instructions after the buffer.
For better explanation, let's break your bytes definition into a few words:
: create-bytes ( u.size "name" -- ) create allot ;
: bytes-action ( u.offset addr1 -- addr2 ) + ;
: alter-bytes-latest ( -- ) does> bytes-action ;
: bytes ( u.size "name" -- ) create-bytes alter-bytes-latest ;

Thus, 10 bytes a is equivalent to the following commands sequence:

10 create-bytes a
alter-bytes-latest

After the command 10 create-bytes a you will get a definition for a that conceptually looks as:

data addr1: header
code addr2: push addr5
code addr3: exit nop nop
code addr4: nop
data addr5: buffer

At this point, each of the commands a ., ' a >body . and here 10 - . prints the same addr5.
After the subsequent alter-bytes-latest command execution, the definition for a will conceptually look like this:

data addr1: header
code addr2: push addr5
code addr3: call bytes-action
code addr4: exit
data addr5: buffer

Now we must pass an offset to a.  The command 0 a . prints addr5, 10 a here = . prints -1.
So alter-bytes-latest just modifies the behavior of a (that is the latest named definition at the moment). Formally, it replaces the execution semantics of the most recent definition (that shall be created via create), see 6.1.1250 DOES>.
See also my illustrative portable implementation for create, >body, and does>.

Your bytes word doesn't allot any space for itself.  It is a word that creates words that have space allocated.
bytes will compile it's CREATE code and compile the DOES> code.
When bytes creates a it allots the space for a and compiles a word a that pushes the data address of a to the stack and calls the DOES> code. How that works will be specific to the forth system.  This simulates what is happening as bytes creates a
10 
HERE SWAP ALLOT CONSTANT a-pointer  \ a-pointer is the address at HERE 
: bytes-does + ;
\ This happens in bytes but without explicitly creating and naming the constant

: a a-pointer bytes-does ;        \ This code runs each time a is called: 

\ Or printing some tracing values
HERE DUP . 10 ALLOT CONSTANT a-pointer  
\ Printed:  5285032  \ This number is specific to my system.

: a a-pointer bytes-does ;    
0 a . 5 a .
\ Printed:  5285032 5285037  ok  The HERE and 5 + HERE

In the word header there is a pointer to the xt of the word. For a this will point past the data to the code to execute.
